# Guardar un dato de la variable global $_SESSION en otra variable

Tags: php, yii2

Buenas tardes a todos. Tengo una duda en como obtener y guardar los valores de $_SESSION en especial solo quiero un id que trae. Pongo estas líneas de código de como veo lo que tiene:

```
$userLog = $_SESSION['usuario'];
dd($userLog); //Con esto se imprime todo lo que contiene el array
```

Y sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo solo quiero el número que tiene PK_USUARIO, en este caso el 82, pero no se como hacerle para guardar el valor en una variable. ¿Cuál seria la forma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que tu variable de sesión es una array matricial asociativa debes acceder al dato mediante las llaves asociativas, intenta con esto:

```
$pk_usuario = $userLog['INFO_EMP']['PK_EMPLEADO'];
```

Así puedes acceder a cualquier dato particular sin importar las dimensiones del array

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, solo que me marca error... Undefined index: PK_USUARIO :(

Comment: Disculpa ya la actualice

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias Ángel Hernández :)